# Allowing Access to my API via js

Tags: jquery, json, api, rest

Do I need to do anything special with my REST Api to allow outside access to the calls via javascript?  It works fine when using CURL but users are having issue when using js.

The webservice simply spits out json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you either need to have your API support JSONP[1], or you need to add CORS headers[2].

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

This is because of the browser's same-origin policy, which prevents you from making AJAX requests to other domains (or subdomains). I would say that adding CORS headers is generally considered to be the "better" way.